# Passing html elements into a jade file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Is it possible to pass HTML elements into a jade file e.g. I would like for the following to populate the p element with text, and a code element with some contained text nested inside the p element.

**JSON containing strings**

```
var news = {
  one : {
    title : "Using JSON",
     body : "Using JSON is a great way of passing information into the jade template files."+
            "It can be looped over using jades each syntax <code>test</code>"
  },
  two : {
    title : "",
    body : ""
  }
}
```

**Routing the HTTP request**

```
// Routes
app.get(navigation.home.uri, function(req, res){ //Home
  res.render(navigation.home.url, {
    title: navigation.home.title,
    navigation: navigation,
    news: news
  });
});
```

**Jade file snippet, with a loop for each news item**

```
  section#news
    - each item in news
      article(class="news")
        header
          h2 #{item.title}
        p #{item.body}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `!{item.body}` instead of `#`

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is indeed correct for the example given by @Jack, however I used this without an initial `p` tag:

```
block content
    .jumbotron
        !{template.sections.welcome}
    .panel.panel-default
        !{template.sections.headline}
```

And this is not correct and will throw up some Jade warnings like

```
Warning: missing space before text for line 6 of jade file "~/demo/views/home.jade"
```

This is because instead of using [Unescaped Buffered Code](http://jade-lang.com/reference/#unescapedbufferedcode) it is using interpolated and is intended for use with long strings.

So the correct syntax (as explained [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/1535)) would be:

```
block content
    .jumbotron
        != template.sections.welcome
    .panel.panel-default
        != template.sections.headline
```

Hope this saves someone some time trying to get to the bottom of those warnings!